# Using multiple dropdown lists to fill one column on db using PostType Form in Symfony 3

Tags: php, twig, symfony-forms, symfony

I have the following situation:
I have two dropdown lists which both values need to be stored on the same db colum. My question is how can I work this out on my **buildForm** method as well as on **html.twig**?
I'd like to thank you all for your help.
Here are my codes:

**Entity**

```
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Diningroom", type="text")
 */
private $diningroom;
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Kitchen", type="text")
 */
private $kitchen;
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Office", type="text")
 */
private $office;
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="BedRoom", type="text")
 */
private $bedroom;
```

**buildForm**

```
        ->add('firstName')
        ->add('lastName')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('telephone')
        ->add('county')
        ->add('city')
        ->add('street')
        ->add('postcode')
        ->add('floor', 'entity')
        ->add('elevator', 'entity')
        ->add('diningroom')
        ->add('kitchen')
        ->add('office')
        ->add('bedroom')
        ->add('bathrooms')
        ->add('boxes')
        ->add('message')
        ->add('packing')
        ->add('personrequired')
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Get Quotation'
    //        'class' => 'btn btn-danger pull right'
        ))
```

**Controller**

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    //create a new post
    $removalPost = new Post();
    $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $removalPost, [
    'action' => $request->getUri()
]);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $removalPost->setAuthor($this->getUser());
        $removalPost->setDate(new \DateTime());
        $em->persist($removalPost);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('RemovalsUK_view',
            ['id' => $removalPost->getId()]));
    }
    return $this->render('RemovalsUKBundle:Post:create.html.twig', array
    ('form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

**My HTML**

```
                    <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Table</label>
                                        <select class="form-control required" name="kitchen_table" id="kitchen_table">
                                            <option value="" selected>Quantity</option>
                                            <option value="0">0</option>
                                            <option value="1">1</option>
                                            <option value="2">2</option>
                                            <option value="3">3</option>
                                            <option value="4">4</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Seat</label>
                                        <select class="form-control required" name="kitchen_seat" id="kitchen_seat">
                                            <option value="" selected>Quantity</option>
                                            <option value="0">0</option>
                                            <option value="1">1</option>
                                            <option value="2">2</option>
                                            <option value="3">3</option>
                                            <option value="4">4</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                           </div>
```

What I want to do is for instance, is insert into kitchen column the values (Quantity) from **Table** and **Seat** 
I would appreciate any any to sort this matter out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would say create getter for kitchen_table and kitchen_seat to fill the form.
For save is the question in which format do you want to save?

```
$data = $form->getData(); 
$removalPost->setKitchen($data['kitchen_table'].'_'.$data['kitchen_seat']);
```

and this should set.
But you also have an issue by setting up your form. the Form should fit with your fields otherwise you cannot get the data via the form, you than have to get the data via the request...

Comment: Thanks I'll try your solution, and yes I will make sure my form will fit the fields, thanks.